# Update sliding menu in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, android-camera, navigation-drawer

I have created a slider menu in my android app which has User profile picture. Initially i am setting a image from app resource folder. once user click this it takes user to edit info fragment where he can capture image or choose image from gallery. How to update selected image profile image in slider menu. [image: update guest image after capturing or selecting from gallery]

any suggestion will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the Sliding menu lib present in github?

Comment: no i am creating my own using list view

Comment: Ok, then u need to notify the view once u have updated so that changes will get reflect in that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same issue with my app like you are facing.
So what i did is :-
1. created an static object of adapter of sliding drawer/menu.
2. and in activity result method while receiving resulting bitmap i have called `ClassName.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

And It works for me..!

Comment: hey...! have you done with this or still i need to post code snippet.? because its almost 21 hours went.

Answer (score 0):

On activity:

```
public ListView mDrawerListView;
```

On fragment:

```
MenuAdapter menuAdapter = (MenuAdapter) ((MainActivity)getActivity()).mDrawerListView.getAdapter();

menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```